# asynctask working in emulator with api 24 and not working in real device with api 28

Tags: java, android

i am using asynctask to fetch data from my hosted web page using the default java httpurlconnection library and apparently the doinbackground method does not execute on my android 9 device but i can receive the json response when tested with emulator api 24. also i declared internet permission in the manifest and i have firebase woking fine, so no internet problem. is there any explanation for this situation? is there any solution while keep using asynctask with httpurlconnection? please help, i have to present my app in two days.

sendDataAsync.class

```
package com.example.control;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

class sendDataAsync extends AsyncTask<String , Void , String>{

            private AsyncResponse delegate = null;
            private String serverURL, responsemsg = "Not connected to host",entries;

            public sendDataAsync(String name, String prename, String email, String gender, String password, String cfirmpassword) {
                entries  = "name="+name+"&prename="+prename+"&email="+email+"&gender="+gender+"&password="+password+"&cfirmpassword="+cfirmpassword;
                serverURL = "http://iotcontrol.atwebpages.com/Register.php";
            }

            public sendDataAsync(String email, String password) {
                entries  = "password="+password+"&email="+email;
                serverURL = "http://iotcontrol.atwebpages.com/Login.php";
            }

            public void setDelegate(AsyncResponse del){
                this.delegate = del;
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    //entries = URLEncoder.encode(entries,"utf-8");
                    URL url = new URL(serverURL);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    writer.write(entries);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    os.close();

                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    String inputLine;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    is.close();
                    conn.disconnect();
                    responsemsg = sb.toString();

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return responsemsg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                delegate.processFinish(result);
            }

        }
```

in my activity i have this

```
  public void insertData() {
    sendDataAsync sendPostReqAsyncTask = new sendDataAsync(nameValue, prenameValue, emailValue, genderValue,passwordValue,cfirmpasswordValue);
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.setDelegate(this);
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute();
  }
/*
for some reason i cant access logcat so i just have a textview and print the response to it

and while on the emulator api24 i have the text view: {"ok":false,"message":"invalide data"}
but on my android 9 phone i have the text: Not connected to host
*/
  public void processFinish(String output) {
    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    txt.setText(output);
  }
```

Comment: It would be great if you show us your `AsyncTask` implementation

Comment: Show also how you call your async task and how you set delegate.  And tell which exceptions you have.

Comment: i edited my question so i have all details. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Android 9, cleartext traffic such as http is not permitted by default.

If the server supports it, use https instead.

If the server does not support https, you need to specifically opt in for cleartext traffic. You can do it app-wide with [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) but it's better to enable it only for one host with [network security config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted).

Comment: thank you so mutch, i added the attribute android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the application tag in the manifest file. i know it is a security issue but my app will run only for one day so i just want the basic tasks to be done in the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly looks like an issue of Cleartext. Please follow the below shared link
https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6

If it's cleartext issue, check your logcat, it will throw an error in logcat.

Plus please note that Async Task has been [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) from **API 30**. Since you are using Java you can start looking into RXJAVA for this and retrofit to make API calls.

Comment: thank you for the answer, it helped. for now i just need to run my app on api 28 , after that i will start looking after performance, compatibility and many other improvement.

Comment: glad it helped. but yes do change the code to new standards. will be helpful in long run